# Resource from int

Tags: android, textview

When I have a source with this:

```
TextView localTV = (TextView)findViewById(2312345);
```

is there a way to kindly ask the compiler to transform it into the resource with its real name, like:

```
TextView localTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
```

Comment: Why would you have `findViewById(2312345)`?

Comment: because that's the source code I received for maintenance. Someone has terribly messed up things and I am here to fix it...

Comment: Was R not recognized? And this is your workaround? You need to fix the project setup or whatever else is wrong instead. There are a lot of questions and answers on that topic.

Comment: OMG... Well, I hope you got the project loaded correctly and that `R` can be loaded. Then you'll have to figure out what id is what in layouts etc... But yes, you can replace ids by `R.id.*`.

Comment: R is recognised and resources do exist. But there are hundreds of cases I need to fix and searching in R for each of them will keep me busy for a week or so, with no guarantee to get it right 100%. So, it would help me if I could have this done by editor.

Answer (score 1):

> When I have a source with this

The most likely reason for having that code would be that the code was decompiled from an APK.

> is there a way to kindly ask the compiler to transform it into the resource with its real name

No, for the simple reason that there may not be a resource corresponding with that number. As soon as you loaded this decompiled app into an IDE, all the resources would be assigned numbers that may or may not match the hardcoded values from the decompiled code.

Answer (score 0):

You should open the layer.xml of the activity or the fragment you are working on and then find the textView and add it an id like this.

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My local TV" />
```

this will create a variable in the R.java with an int that you will not have to handle by your self. you only call

```
TextView localTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
```

But if you do not have Xml layout and it is created programaticaly, you should go to res/values/ids.xml  (if you do not find ids.xml you can create it ) and add an ID like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<item name="mytext" type="id" />
<item name="navBarText" type="id" />
<item name="navBarImg" type="id" />


</resources>
```

and when you create the textView programaticaly you set an Id for the TextView like this

```
menuLayout.setId(R.id.mytext);
```

and then you can call the TextView by using

```
TextView localTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
```